# Understand Precision and recall and F-mesure

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

I am trying to display the precision, recall and F-mesure but there are extremely low, do you know why ?

```
total_verbatim = X.shape[0]
print(total_verbatim)
labels = np.zeros(total_verbatim);#creation de variable ; consulter les mal étiquettés +bien étiquettés
#error avec configuration avec l'ensemble 
labels[1:1315]=0; #motivations
labels[1316:1891]=1;#freins


cv_splitter = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
model1 = LinearSVC()
model2 = MultinomialNB()
models = [model1, model2]
for model in models:    
    #verbatim_preprocess = np.array(verbatim_train_remove_stop_words_lemmatize)
    y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X, labels, cv=cv_splitter)
    print("Model: {}".format(model))
    print("matrice confusion: {}".format(confusion_matrix(labels, y_pred)))
    print("Accuracy: {}".format(accuracy_score(labels, y_pred)))
    print("Precision: {}".format(precision_score(labels, y_pred)))
    print("Recall: {}".format(recall_score(labels, y_pred)))
    print("F mesure: {}".format(f1_score(labels, y_pred)))
```

there is the result , when computing manually the result are much higher for the precision and recall :

```
Model: LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=True, fit_intercept=True,
     intercept_scaling=1, loss='squared_hinge', max_iter=1000,
     multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001,
     verbose=0)
matrice confusion: [[963 353]
 [518  57]]
Accuracy: 0.5393971443680592
Precision: 0.13902439024390245
Recall: 0.09913043478260869
F mesure: 0.11573604060913706
Model: MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
matrice confusion: [[1248   68]
 [ 574    1]]
Accuracy: 0.6604970914859862
Precision: 0.014492753623188406
Recall: 0.0017391304347826088
F mesure: 0.0031055900621118015
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oui. The classification model is not good.**

By looking only at the confusion matrix of the first model:

```
matrice confusion: [[963 353]
                    [518  57]]
```

**You can see that 353 from class 1 and 518 samples from class 2 are misclassified respectively.**

Ideally, you should have counts only on the diagonal.

**Also, the Accuracy it's almost 0.5 i.e., you predict at chance level.**

Similarily, for model 2.

---

To improve the models try to play with different hyperparameters of the models and different Folds numbers.

Do a `GridSearch` [see here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

Comment: Furthermore, the accuracy for the MultinimialNB is only as (relatively) high as it is due to the dataset being imbalanced. It is overfit to primarily predict class 0.